# How to open port on IIS Firewall

Tags: asp.net, iis

In doc of http://www.telerik.com/team-productivity-tools.aspx it says

> In order to access the TeamPulse
>   components from client machines, you
>   will need to open the following ports
>   in your frewall: • 9898 – TeamPulse
>   Client Site • 9899 – TeamPulse
>   Synchronizaton Service • 8734 –
>   TeamPulse Synchronizaton Service •
>   2431 – TeamPulse User Administraton
>   Sit

When I go to firewall in list of programs I can't see any teampulse program listed throuh I'm connected to it.

Comment: Which version of Windows do you have?

Comment: Windows 2008 Web Edition

Comment: Can you kindly let me know if the problem is fixed?

Comment: yes it's fixed with your solution sorry I forgot to vote ! I don't come here often.

Comment: glade to hear this. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can follow the next steps in order to open the required port in your Windows firewall:

1- Open "Windows Firewall with advanced security"

2- Go to Inbound Rules and add the ports one by one:

1- 9898 – TeamPulse Client Site
2- 9899
   – TeamPulse Synchronizaton Service
   3- 8734 – TeamPulse Synchronization
   Service
   4- 2431 – TeamPulse User Administraton
   Sit

let me know if this worked for you